# Does GWTQuery support the CSS Selector [attr*="some_val"]?

Tags: gwt, css-selectors, gwtquery

I have been using GQuery for a while now. 
I recently came across some unexpected behaviour.

I have 2 different scenarios:

a) I want to select an element say

```
<a href="http://example.com?p=site:helloworld.com">Link</a>
```

I used

```
GQuery.$("a[href*=site:helloworld.com]")
```

This doesn't seem to work.

b) The other thing I wish to select is

```
<h1 data-title="SampleTitle">Title</h1>
```

I need to extract the value of data-title. I used the following:

```
GQuery.$("h1").attr("data-title");
```

Now, this doesn't return an error but it doesn't return the value either. It just returns a blank String. This doesn't have anything to do with the '-', is it?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) I did a quick test, and the selector works fine! (But you have to quote the value as mentioned in another answer: `GQuery.$("a[href*=\"site:helloworld.com\"]")`)

<sub>*Note:* The "*=" selector is defined in CSS 3. Gwtquery usually only supports CSS 2 at the moment, see http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/CssGuide#CSS_scope</sub>

b) `GQuery.$("h1").attr("data-title");` works for me: It returns the full attribute string value of the **first** "h1" element in the document

I'm using gwtquery 1.1.0 + GWT 2.4.0. If possible, try to upgrade to these (or later) versions.

Comment: about the note, that is the set of attributes supported via the type-save mechanism, ie: `$("div").css(CSS.BACKGROUND.with(...))`, but gquery supports CSS2 and CSS3 via key/value syntax `$("div").css("background", ...)`. The query selector also supports CSS2/CSS3 selectors.